# Enabling beep in Ubuntu12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

A duplicate of [Enable System Beep in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/22767/enable-system-beep-in-ubuntu). Nothing mentioned there worked.

I'm trying to enable beep in my `Ubuntu 12.04` laptop and `Ubuntu 14.04` desktop.

- `cout << "\a"` in g++
- `echo -e "\a"` in bash

I want the above two to produce a beep.

I followed [this](http://earthwithsun.com/questions/22767/enable-system-beep-in-ubuntu) and searched it at other places, but nothing works. I have commented out `blacklist pcspkr` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. I have also enabled it in `alsamixer`.

```
> sudo apt-get install beep
> beep    // produces beep
> sudo modprobe pcspkr    // shows nothing
> lsmod | grep pcspkr 
pcspkr                 12631  0 
> sudo grep pcspkr /var/log/dmesg 
[   16.278105] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input8
> pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg bell.ogg
> pactl list samples     // shows bell.ogg
```

But how do I make it beep using `\a` (esp in g++)?

Comment: `\a` producing a sound depends on the terminal settings as well. Have you enabled (audible) terminal bells in the terminal settings?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Many sound cards have a "beep" channel, often muted:
run "alsamixer" in a terminal : you may need to press F6 and select your card. scroll to the Beep channel using the arrow keys and press M to unmute the channel. notice that the "MM" label below the channel will change to "00". you can also use ↑ to increase the volume of the channel.
press Esc to close alsamixer.

(From [archwiki: beep](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beep))